# Shortest job first job with preemption allowed Anamoly

Tags: operating-system, scheduling

Consider the following scenario, and take this as preemptive Shortest first job executing algorithm.
[image: SJF][1]

The problem here is at the timeline (3), p2 has 1 burst time available, but p4 which is now available has 2 burst time, so my question is why is p2 is not continuing the execution, and why p4 is starting?, Is this diagram wrong or have i misunderstood in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gantt chart has to be like:

[image]

Average waiting time should be [(0+11) + 0 + 4 + 9] /4 =6.